# For how many total hours had Arecibo transmitted a signal?

Tags: radio-communication, radio-telescope, meti

**Update:** Sadly, parts of the dish have collapsed, several cables have snapped, and the Arecibo radio telescope is now decommissioned and demolition has been recommended because it is now too unsafe to do anything else.

- [NSF begins planning for decommissioning of Arecibo Observatory’s 305-meter telescope due to safety concerns](https://www.nsf.gov/news/news_summ.jsp?cntn_id=301674)
- [Iconic radio telescope in Puerto Rico to be demolished](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/2020/11/historic-radio-telescope-in-puerto-rico-to-be-demolished/)

Perhaps an answer now can pay tribute to Arecibo's monumental half-century contribution to science!

---

Although it is technically a radio telescope for astronomy and radar ranging, the Arecibo Observatory has been used for Messaging for Extra-Terrestrial Intelligence ([meti](/questions/tagged/meti)).  **For how many total hours had Arecibo been used to transmit a signal?**

If your reference source distinguishes between METI, radar, and/or other types of transmissions, please include this information in your answer.

Related: [Does man send any signal to attract aliens?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1567/26446)

Comment: In case you are also interested in messages sent by other telescopes, this article might be interesting: https://www.newscientist.com/article/2153461-we-just-sent-a-message-to-try-to-talk-to-aliens-on-another-world/

Comment: Arecibo's transmitter was capable of [a whopping 1 megawatt](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30281/12102), so perhaps a followup question could be "How many Joules has Arecibo removed from the Earth? :-)

Comment: related in Astronomy SE: [Are we less safe now that Arecibo is decommissioned and will be demolish?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38585/7982)

Comment: @uhoh With a high albedo surface, probably a lot more Joules in the form of sunlight than radio waves.

Answer (score 3):

The telescope had a very powerful ([1 MW at 12.6 cm wavelength](http://www.naic.edu/%7Enolan/radar/)) radar that has been used to investigate surroundings.  Radar images of [asteroids](http://www.naic.edu/%7Enolan/radar/R1172/) and planets like [Venus](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/PSJ/ac4f43), [Mars](https://repository.si.edu/handle/10088/18820), [Lunar poles](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.276.5318.1527) have been obtained. The total time of transmission is not obvious but assuming multiple projects, it was definitely much more than just [Arecibo message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message) that was transmitted only at 450 kW with the older system before upgrade. Other sources also mention [5 MW](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-detectable-range-of-an-Arecibo-planetary-radar-like-transmitter-5-MW-continuous-wave_fig1_224263754) transmissions.

The alien mind may or may not figure out that they origin of these pulses is not natural.

Comment: That is a good point. My answer was clearly and specifically about only the total hours of official METI broadcasts.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only official METI messages broadcast by Arecibo were the original 3 minute [1974 message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message), and a [WOW! Reply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wow!_signal#Response) in 2012 that took not more than 8 hours.

The Wow! Reply broadcast was booked in the Arecibo telescope schedule from [9 am to 5 pm AST on 15 August 2012](https://www.naic.edu/vscience/schedule/image/.old/Aug_12_12.html). About [20000 tweets](https://geeksofdoom.com/2012/08/18/national-geographic-arecibo-observatory-beam-20000-messages-out-to-space-in-reply-to-the-wow-signal) were broadcast at [about 1 Tweet per second](http://web.archive.org/web/20120819043043/http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/channel/chasing-ufos/the-wow-signal-how-we-ll-reply/#page=2), plus some invited 72-second videos. This is consistent with the 8-hour broadcast window.